# Polymer and firebase-auth

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, firebase-authentication

I am writing a polymer web application. I am using firebase along with firebase-auth for my db and authentication.

I have a main `app.html` element on my index page with a custom `my-login` element that pops up when you click a login button that contains my `firebase-auth` element and login logic. So far I have been able to successfully log in with the `firebase-auth` element. However, after logging in with the `my-login` element, I have not been able to figure out how to access the login information back on my index.html page and all of the other pages in my app.

Any idea on how to do this? I can't find any examples online of using login information on elements other than the one that contains the `firebase-auth`.

Here is my `app.html`:

```
<dom-module id="my-app">
    <link rel="import" type="css" href="../styles/app-theme.css">
    <template>
        <app-router style="display:none;">
            <app-route path="/" import="/elements/blog.html"></app-route>
            <app-route path="/artist" import="/elements/artist.html"></app-route>
            <app-route path="/teacher" import="/elements/teacher.html"></app-route>
            <app-route path="/research" import="/elements/research.html"></app-route>
            <app-route path="/contact" import="/elements/contact.html"></app-route>
            <app-route path="*" import="/elements/blog.html"></app-route>
        </app-router>

        <!-- Main Area -->
        <paper-scroll-header-panel main fixed>
            <!-- Main Toolbar -->
            <paper-toolbar class="medium-tall">

                <div class="">
                    <div class="app-name">Joyce K. Lee</div>
                    <span class="spacer"></span>
                    <paper-icon-button icon="account-circle" onclick="login.open()" hidden?="{{!statusKnown || user}}"></paper-icon-button>
                    <paper-icon-button icon="account-square" onclick="{{logout}}" hidden?="{{!statusKnown || !user}}"></paper-icon-button>
                    <template if="{{user}}">
                        {{user.password.username}}
                    </template>
                </div>

                <div class="bottom center fit">
                    <paper-tabs id="nav" selected="{{selected}}">
                        <paper-tab><a href="#/"><iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
                        <paper-tab><a href="#/artist"><iron-icon icon="custom-icons:brush"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
                        <paper-tab><a href="#/teacher"><iron-icon icon="custom-icons:apple"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
                        <paper-tab><a href="#/research"><iron-icon icon="custom-icons:book"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
                        <paper-tab><a href="#/contact"><iron-icon icon="mail"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
                    </paper-tabs>
                </div>
            </paper-toolbar>

            <!-- Main Content -->
            <div class="content">
                <neon-animated-pages style="height:100%" id="pages" class="flex" selected="{{selected}}" entry-animation="slide-from-right-animation" exit-animation="slide-left-animation">
                    <neon-animatable><my-blog></my-blog></neon-animatable>
                    <neon-animatable><my-artist></my-artist></neon-animatable>
                    <neon-animatable><my-teacher></my-teacher></neon-animatable>
                    <neon-animatable><my-research></my-research></neon-animatable>
                    <neon-animatable><my-contact></my-contact></neon-animatable>
                </neon-animated-pages>
            </div>

            <simple-overlay id="login" with-backdrop>
                <my-login></my-login>
            </simple-overlay>
        </paper-scroll-header-panel>
    </template>

    <script>
        (function () {
            Polymer({
                is: 'my-app'
            });
        })();
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Here is my working `my-login` element:

```
<dom-module id="my-login">
    <template>
        <firebase-auth id="firebaseLogin" user="{{user}}" status-known="{{statusKnown}}" location="https://brilliant-inferno-6056.firebaseio.com" provider="password" on-error="errorHandler" on-user-created="userSuccessHandler" on-password-changed="userSuccessHandler" on-password-reset="userSuccessHandler" on-user-removed="userSuccessHandler"></firebase-auth>

        <h4>Login</h4>
        <paper-input label="Email" value="{{email::input}}"></paper-input>
        <paper-input label="Password" type="password" value="{{password::input}}"></paper-input>
        <paper-button on-tap="login" raised>Login</paper-button>
        <br>
        <div id="message">[[message]]</div>
        <h3>Login status:</h3>
        <p>{{computeLoginStatus(statusKnown, user)}}</p>
    </template>

    <script>
        (function () {
            'use strict';

            Polymer({
                is: 'my-login',

                properties: {
                    message: {
                        type: String,
                        value: ''
                    },
                    email: {
                        type: String,
                        value: ''
                    },
                    password: {
                        type: String,
                        value: ''
                    },
                    user: {
                        type: Object,
                        value: null,
                        notify: true
                    },
                    statusKnown: {
                        type: Boolean,
                        notify: true
                    }
                },
                login: function () {
                    var params = {};
                    params.email = this.email;
                    params.password = this.password;
                    this.$.firebaseLogin.login(params);
                },
                logout: function () {
                    this.$.firebaseLogin.logout();
                },
                errorHandler: function (e) {
                    this.message = 'Error: ' + e.detail.message;
                },
                userSuccessHandler: function (e) {
                    this.message = e.type + ' success!';
                },
                createUserHandler: function (e) {
                    this.$.firebaseLogin.createUser(this.email, this.password);
                },
                changePasswordHandler: function (e) {
                    this.$.firebaseLogin.changePassword(this.email, this.password, this.newPassword);
                },
                resetPasswordHandler: function (e) {
                    this.$.firebaseLogin.sendPasswordResetEmail(this.email);
                },
                removeUserHandler: function (e) {
                    this.$.firebaseLogin.removeUser(this.email, this.password);
                },
                computeCreateUserDisabled: function (email, password) {
                    return !email || !password;
                },
                computeChangePasswordDisabled: function (email, password, newPassword) {
                    return !email || !password || !newPassword;
                },
                computeResetPasswordDisabled: function (email, password) {
                    return !email || !password;
                },
                computeRemoveUserDisabled: function (email, password) {
                    return !email || !password;
                },
                computeLoginHidden: function (statusKnown, user) {
                    return !statusKnown || !!user;
                },
                computeLogoutHidden: function (statusKnown, user) {
                    return !statusKnown || !user;
                },
                computeLoginStatus: function (statusKnown, user) {
                    if (statusKnown && user) {
                        return 'Logged in';
                    }
                    if (statusKnown) {
                        return 'Logged out';
                    }
                    return 'Unknown (checking status...)';
                }
            });
        })();
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the user object in my-login to a property my-app. The user object mind you probably doesn't hold everything you want so you'll most likely need to add a firebase-document which fetches the additional information you need.  Same thing applies, bind the result of that object just like user in my-app.

```
<dom-module id="my-app">
<link rel="import" type="css" href="../styles/app-theme.css">
<template>
    <app-router style="display:none;">
        <app-route path="/" import="/elements/blog.html"></app-route>
        <app-route path="/artist" import="/elements/artist.html"></app-route>
        <app-route path="/teacher" import="/elements/teacher.html"></app-route>
        <app-route path="/research" import="/elements/research.html"></app-route>
        <app-route path="/contact" import="/elements/contact.html"></app-route>
        <app-route path="*" import="/elements/blog.html"></app-route>
    </app-router>

    <!-- Main Area -->
    <paper-scroll-header-panel main fixed>
        <!-- Main Toolbar -->
        <paper-toolbar class="medium-tall">

            <div class="">
                <div class="app-name">Joyce K. Lee</div>
                <span class="spacer"></span>
                <paper-icon-button icon="account-circle" onclick="login.open()" hidden?="{{!statusKnown || user}}"></paper-icon-button>
                <paper-icon-button icon="account-square" onclick="{{logout}}" hidden?="{{!statusKnown || !user}}"></paper-icon-button>
                <template if="{{user}}">
                    {{user.password.username}}
                </template>
            </div>

            <div class="bottom center fit">
                <paper-tabs id="nav" selected="{{selected}}">
                    <paper-tab><a href="#/"><iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
                    <paper-tab><a href="#/artist"><iron-icon icon="custom-icons:brush"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
                    <paper-tab><a href="#/teacher"><iron-icon icon="custom-icons:apple"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
                    <paper-tab><a href="#/research"><iron-icon icon="custom-icons:book"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
                    <paper-tab><a href="#/contact"><iron-icon icon="mail"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
                </paper-tabs>
            </div>
        </paper-toolbar>

        <!-- Main Content -->
        <div class="content">
            <neon-animated-pages style="height:100%" id="pages" class="flex" selected="{{selected}}" entry-animation="slide-from-right-animation" exit-animation="slide-left-animation">
                <neon-animatable><my-blog user="{{user}}"></my-blog></neon-animatable>
                <neon-animatable><my-artist user="{{user}}"></my-artist></neon-animatable>
                <neon-animatable><my-teacher user="{{user}}"></my-teacher></neon-animatable>
                <neon-animatable><my-research user="{{user}}"></my-research></neon-animatable>
                <neon-animatable><my-contact user="{{user}}"></my-contact></neon-animatable>
            </neon-animated-pages>
        </div>

        <simple-overlay id="login" with-backdrop>
            <my-login user="{{user}}"></my-login>
        </simple-overlay>
    </paper-scroll-header-panel>
</template>

<script>
    (function () {
        Polymer({
            is: 'my-app'
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who needs this, the user object is going to be shared in your app if you use one instant of  and you should be able to access it in your elements by say, user.uid to get the ID of user. Just paste a  in your elements.

put this in your index.html

```
<firebase-app   
  id="firApp" 
  name="AnyName"
  api-key = "******************"
  auth-domain = "**************"
  database-url = "***************"
  storage-bucket = "*****************"
  messaging-sender-id = "************">
</firebase-app>
```

So your element will be something like:

```
<dom-module id="my-view">
  <template>
  <style> 
.....
</style> 


 <!-- user is null if no user -->
    <firebase-auth
      id="auth"
      app-name="AnyName"
      provider="facebook"    ***for example
      signed-in="{{signedIn}}"      
      user="{{user}}">
    </firebase-auth>

 <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-view',

      properties: {
        signedIn: {
          type: Boolean,
          notify: true,
          value: false
        }
      },
  });

  </script>
</dom-module>
```

You can add a string property for user as well and bind it to the firebase-auth user, etc. Remember to import polyfire.html and install it if you have not. Cheers